# Can't get margin, padding, or font CSS to work with display: flex; CSS code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm in the process of learning how to code, and am trying to build my own website. Currently working on the welcome screen where a user can login/sign up. I have the login section working perfectly with the display: block; flex-direction: column; and all the font, margin, and alignment CSS commands, but the sign up section absolutely refuses to cooperate with the font and margin commands as display: flex;.

Below is my code.

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const loginLink = document.querySelector('.login-link');
const registerLink = document.querySelector('.register-link');
const btnPopup = document.querySelector('.btnLogin-popup');
const iconClose = document.querySelector('.icon-close');

registerLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
  wrapper.classList.add('active');
});

loginLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
  wrapper.classList.remove('active');
});

btnPopup.addEventListener('click', () => {
  wrapper.classList.add('active-popup');
});

iconClose.addEventListener('click', () => {
  wrapper.classList.remove('active-popup');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 99;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Charm', cursive;
  color: hsl(270, 100%, 75%);
  user-select: none;
}

.navigation a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: aquamarine;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.navigation a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 18px;
  border: none;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.navigation a:hover::after {
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.navigation .btnLogin-popup {
  background-color: purple;
  color: aquamarine;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
}

.navigation .btnLogin-popup:hover {
  background-color: #b76aff;
  color: aqua;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 440px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  border-radius: 20px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: tranform .5s ease, height .2s ease;
}

.wrapper.active-popup {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.wrapper.active {
  height: 520px;
}

.wrapper .form-box {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
}

.wrapper .form-box.login {
  transition: transform .18s ease;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.wrapper.active .form-box.login {
  transition: none;
  transform: translateX(400px);
}

.wrapper .form-box.register {
  position: absolute;
  transition: none;
  transform: translateX(400px);
}

.wrapper.active .form-box.register {
  transition: none;
  transform: translateX(400px);
}

.wrapper .icon-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: purple;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: aquamarine;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form-box h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
}

.input-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid purple;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.input-box label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: purple;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

.input-box input:focus~label,
.input-box input:valid~label {
  top: -5px;
}

.input-box input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 35px 0 5px;
}

.input-box .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: purple;
  line-height: 57px;
}

.remember-forgot {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: purple;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: -15px 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.remember-forgot label input {
  accent-color: purple;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.remember-forgot a {
  color: purple;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.remember-forgot a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: purple;
  color: aquamarine;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.login-register {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 25px 0 10px;
}

.login-register p a {
  color: purple;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.login-register p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vakaroria Virtual Pet Site</title>
  <Link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h2 class="logo">Vakaroria Virtual Pets</h2>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <a href="#">Welcome</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Campaign</a>
      <a href="#">Pet Creation</a>
      <a href="#">Player Sales</a>
      <a href="#">Site Sales</a>
      <a href="#">Games</a>
      <a href="#">Forums</a>
      <a href="#">Index</a>
      <button class="btnLogin-popup">Login!</button>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="icon-close">
        <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
      </span>
    <div class="form-box login">
      <h2>Login!</h2>
      <form action="#">
        <div class="input-box">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
            </span>
          <input type="email" required>
          <label>Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="lock-closed"></ion-icon></span>
          <input type="password" required>
          <label>Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="remember-forgot">
          <label><input type="checkbox">Remember Me!</label>
          <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Login!</button>
        <div class="login-register">
          <p>Don't have an account?<a href="#" class="register-link">Register!</a></p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="form-box register">
      <h2>Registration</h2>
      <form action="#">
        <div class="input-box">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
            </span>
          <input type="text" required>
          <label>Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
            </span>
          <input type="email" required>
          <label>Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="lock-closed"></ion-icon></span>
          <input type="password" required>
          <label>Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="remember-forgot">
          <label><input type="checkbox">I agree to the terms & conditions</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Register!</button>
        <div class="login-register">
          <p>Already have an account?<a href="#" class="login-link">Login!</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I change it to display: block; it no longer conforms to the flex-direction: column; command unlike the login section. I need it to be in a column, not a line, and have spacing between the different boxes, as well as being able to adjust the text size within the boxes. I'm using VSCode to write all my code. The body {background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 23%);} command also isn't working, and I'm just trying to change the site from a white color.

Comment: What do you see as the css which is being used when you use your browsers dev tools inspect facility?

Comment: could you please add your HTML structure as well, it would better for other used to predict the problem you are facing and could give you best solution.

Comment: @Nikkkshit I actually started over on the site and have an entirely new structure, but ran into yet another issue. Essentially the new issue is you click the login button in the top right corner of the screen, and it opens a small in site pop up window that gives you the login form, when you click register it's supposed to give you the register form instead, but for some reason the register form won't show up, and I cannot for the life of me find where I messed up the code.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mlbWzJ39KRUbufFefEyYenGQxYMg-EYuPeTHufhCVpU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

- You are forgoting to get form back to where it is. When you add class active you are not bringing `transform: translateX(0)` to `0` from `transform: translateX(400px)`.
- Changes are on line 136 in css. my solution.

**Please see result in full page mode.**

[image: Full page view output]

```css
.wrapper.active .form-box.register {
  transition: none;
  transform: translateX(0); // we are setting back to 0 px to its main position
}
```

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const loginLink = document.querySelector('.login-link');
const registerLink = document.querySelector('.register-link');
const btnPopup = document.querySelector('.btnLogin-popup');
const iconClose = document.querySelector('.icon-close');

registerLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
  wrapper.classList.add('active');
});

loginLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
  wrapper.classList.remove('active');
});

btnPopup.addEventListener('click', () => {
  wrapper.classList.add('active-popup');
});

iconClose.addEventListener('click', () => {
  wrapper.classList.remove('active-popup');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 99;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Charm', cursive;
  color: hsl(270, 100%, 75%);
  user-select: none;
}

.navigation a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: aquamarine;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.navigation a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 18px;
  border: none;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.navigation a:hover::after {
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.navigation .btnLogin-popup {
  background-color: purple;
  color: aquamarine;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
}

.navigation .btnLogin-popup:hover {
  background-color: #b76aff;
  color: aqua;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 440px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  border-radius: 20px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: tranform .5s ease, height .2s ease;
}

.wrapper.active-popup {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.wrapper.active {
  height: 520px;
}

.wrapper .form-box {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
}

.wrapper .form-box.login {
  transition: transform .18s ease;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.wrapper.active .form-box.login {
  transition: none;
  transform: translateX(400px);
}

.wrapper .form-box.register {
  position: absolute;
  transition: none;
  transform: translateX(400px);
}


/*------------------------------*/

.wrapper.active .form-box.register {
  transition: none;
  transform: translateX(0);
}


/*------------------------------*/

.wrapper .icon-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: purple;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: aquamarine;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form-box h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
}

.input-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid purple;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.input-box label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: purple;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

.input-box input:focus~label,
.input-box input:valid~label {
  top: -5px;
}

.input-box input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 35px 0 5px;
}

.input-box .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: purple;
  line-height: 57px;
}

.remember-forgot {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: purple;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: -15px 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.remember-forgot label input {
  accent-color: purple;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.remember-forgot a {
  color: purple;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.remember-forgot a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: purple;
  color: aquamarine;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.login-register {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 25px 0 10px;
}

.login-register p a {
  color: purple;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.login-register p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vakaroria Virtual Pet Site</title>
  <Link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h2 class="logo">Vakaroria Virtual Pets</h2>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <a href="#">Welcome</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Campaign</a>
      <a href="#">Pet Creation</a>
      <a href="#">Player Sales</a>
      <a href="#">Site Sales</a>
      <a href="#">Games</a>
      <a href="#">Forums</a>
      <a href="#">Index</a>
      <button class="btnLogin-popup">Login!</button>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="icon-close">
        <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
      </span>
    <div class="form-box login">
      <h2>Login!</h2>
      <form action="#">
        <div class="input-box">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
            </span>
          <input type="email" required>
          <label>Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="lock-closed"></ion-icon></span>
          <input type="password" required>
          <label>Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="remember-forgot">
          <label><input type="checkbox">Remember Me!</label>
          <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Login!</button>
        <div class="login-register">
          <p>Don't have an account?<a href="#" class="register-link">Register!</a></p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="form-box register">
      <h2>Registration</h2>
      <form action="#">
        <div class="input-box">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
            </span>
          <input type="text" required>
          <label>Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
            </span>
          <input type="email" required>
          <label>Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="lock-closed"></ion-icon></span>
          <input type="password" required>
          <label>Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="remember-forgot">
          <label><input type="checkbox">I agree to the terms & conditions</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Register!</button>
        <div class="login-register">
          <p>Already have an account?<a href="#" class="login-link">Login!</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```